# CS50 check50 failing on roster.py PSET7 only showing none for names

Tags: python, sql, cs50

I've been working on PSET7 on CS50 and the code displays the right output in the terminal:
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp1Cn.png)

However when I submit the code and go to check50 it shows I have failed on the roster checks:
[CS50 Check50 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37WXW.png)

My code for the final part is:

```
for rows in range(len(query)):
# set variables for each field
first = str(query[rows].get('FIRST'))
middle = query[rows].get('middle')
last = query[rows].get('LAST')
born = query[rows].get('birth')

# check if middle is blank
if (middle == None):
    print(f'{first} {last}, born {born}')

else:
    print(f'{first} {middle} {last}, born {born}')
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is displaying "none" for the first and last names but displaying the middle names?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, python `get` returns None if the key does not exist, instead of returning a key error. Most likely explanation is that the column names (keys) in the dictionaries returned by the query are not upper case.

Comment: Thanks, what I don't understand is why the code works when I run it in the terminal.

Anyway, I decided to change the names to lowercase and now it works, which means that the check50 db is set up with lowercase names rather than the uppercase that I have. As now when I run the check I get 6/6.